# Работа с классами и функциями в них

Tags: python

Есть два класса. В первом классе есть функция любая и в ней есть значения (допустим a=3; b=4; c=8
не `__init__()`).
Как во втором классе менять значение функции которая находится в первом классе?
Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: приведите образец описания классов, о которых вы говорите, и желаемый результат

Comment: Опишите более внятно, что вы хотите сделать и почему существующие 100500 вопросов и ответов на эту тему вам не помогли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объявить необходимое значение как global, после чего менять его из любой части программы (так делать не рекомендуется, однако для других решений недостаточно информации из вашего вопроса)

Comment: *Как во втором классе менять значение функции* - я конечно, не понимаю смысла этой фразы, но кажется global никак не поможет